# Errors while installing Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install Rstudio. I have downloaded the `rstudio-0.98.1103-deb` package.

This is the error I am getting when I do:

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-0.98.1103-amd64.deb
```

How do I go about the installation? Any suggestions would be great. I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Package libjpeg62 is not installed.`

You can get it by typing this in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

Answer (score 2):

It tells you pretty clearly that you `libjpeg62`.

So do `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62` and then reinstall RStudio.